# solr search, avoid defaultSearchField

Tags: search, solr, field

I have a solr search problem, currently our schema is setup have the following

```
<field name="trading_name" type="trading_name" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true" />
<field name="trading_name_notoken" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true" />
...
<copyField source="trading_name" dest="trading_name_notoken" />
...
<defaultSearchField>trading_name</defaultSearchField>
...
<fieldType name="trading_name" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>...
```

I want to search on trading_name_notoken field instead of trading_name field, how should I build my search query?

Cheers

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `df` (default field) parameter:

```
q=some query&df=trading_name_notoken
```

Comment: using df doesn't return any search results... any ideas?

Comment: forgot string type search is case sensitive

Comment: Is there a way to specify case insensitive search in the query? Or do I have to modify the schema to have a field to allow insensitive searching?

Comment: @James: case sensitiveness depends on each fieldType.

Comment: I would like to have case insensitive on the string field type, is it possible? cheers.

Comment: @James: the string field type is indexed as-is by default, but you can always customize the fieldType and/or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an extra field into SOLR which contains the lower case version of trading_name, hopefully it will sort out my problem

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an analyzer which lowercases terms on that field. Have a look at this [LowerCaseTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory)